# Not able to "Add to Cart' if i am not logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authentication, cart

I have a problem in my Woocommerce shop. Not logged-in users can't add products in their cart! When they press the "add-to-cart-button", it shows the products is added to the cart. But if you go to the cart, it is empty! 
If I am logged-in, it is not happening and everything is working good.
Can someone please help?

Site- [www.filmyvastra.com](https://www.filmyvastra.com)

This is my settings for Woocommerce-->Accounts & Privacy
[image]

Comment: As soon as the product is added to cart, something is clearing the cart. Try deactivating plugins or swtiching themes

Comment: If you are using `wp_engine` plugin or any caching plugin, try deactivating them

Comment: I have tried deactivating all plugins except for woocommerce , the problem was still there.

Comment: What version of woocommerce do you use ?

Comment: The latest one : Woocommerce 3.5.5 | PHP 7.2.6

Comment: Right now I cannot add any of my products to cart.

Comment: waht theme are you using ?

Comment: I am using Oceanwp

Comment: Please switch theme to storefront theme and check for issue